# Override SSL Socket to TLS 1.2 in Java 1.7 and create an HTTP Post JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, sockets, ssl

I'm fairly new to Java, but do have a basic understanding of how the code is structured.

I have a weird case where I need to override the default socket from TLS 1.1 to TLS 1.2 in **Java 1.7**. And after doing this, I need to create an HTTP Post with headers and a JSON message. The JSON I would need to pass would essentially look like below:

```
{
 "firstName": "bob",
 "lastName": "bob",
 "email": "bob",
}
```

After doing some research on HTTP Post, I found that you can set headers by doing something similar to this (I've been able to successfully set headers):

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Content-Type, "application/json");
```

However, when it comes to setting the JSON message using "setEntity", I believe I am doing something incorrectly. I have been receiving a 400 Bad Request Error.

```
post.setEntity(new StringEntity("{\n\"firstName\":\"bob\",\n\"lastName\":\"bob\",\n\"email\":\"bob\"}");
```

1) I don't really understand how to accomplish overriding the default socket from TLS1.1 to TLS1.2.

2) Could it be that the POST API (JSON Message) needs to be formatted exactly as shown, and that I am passing it incorrectly via setEntity?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Changing from TLS 1.1 to 1.2 doesn't require overriding the default socket, and there is nothing in your question that does so.

Comment: My question is: how do you accomplish sending over an HTTP request as TLS 1.2? I don't understand how to do this and was asking for advice on how to do so. I am using an eclipsed based program that defaults to TLS 1.1, and there is no option to set TLS to 1.2. 

Additionally, I don't understand if my setEntity is correct.

Comment: You are asking about 'overriding sockets'. XY problem. I have no idea why my factual comment saying so has been deleted.

Comment: Figured how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: ^ To add to this, yes I had to override the default socket. Not sure if you did not understand the question, or if you did not read my question and initial comment.